# Target Activity pauses before tests cases can be run

Tags: android, testing, android-activity, instrumentation

I'm fairly new to Android testing. I'm trying to run test cases on a target Activity using ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2 and Espresso.

For some reason I can’t explain, when running the activity's test class, the target Activity pauses and a different activity starts before my tests cases can be run. Sometimes I'll see the target Activity load for a split-second, then it defaults to the different Activity. After the other activity has taken over, it runs my test cases (causing the tests to always fail). I’ve spent a lot of time researching why my target Activity is pausing, but I haven’t been able to find anything specific to resolve this problem.

Here is basically what my test class looks like:

```
public class RequestTests extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<RequestActivity> {

    public RequestTests() {
        super(RequestActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        getActivity();
    }

    @LargeTest
    public void testInitialState() throws Exception {
         onView(withId(R.id.validation_hint))
                .perform(scrollTo())
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
         onView(withId(R.id.request_button))
                .check(matches(not(isEnabled())));
    }
}
```

RequestActivity is my target Activity. It gets immediately paused, and one of my other activities, SetupActivity, is run. By the time testInitialState() is run, SetupActivity is running instead of RequestActivity. Why would my target Activity get paused? Any help would be greatly appreciated.